# Create warning message if cell left blank in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

Could someone please assist me with this?

I would like a warning message (data validation) if B3 and C3 equal `"Absent"` or `"Late"` and B4 and C4 are empty?

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: You don't identify a specific programming problem, describe your research or demonstrate how a successful outcome might appear. The "warning message" is undefined, and no explanation for using "data validation". It's unclear if the warning applies to any two consecutive days, or only on Monday's and Tuesday's. I suggest that you re-read [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question to provide addition information.

Answer (score 1):

- data validation custom formula: **`=NOT(ISBLANK(B4))`**
- conditional formatting custom formula: **`=OR(B3="Absent", B3="Late")`**

[image]